# Weird copy constructor error on STL vector

Tags: c++, c++11, game-engine, copy-constructor

So I'm currently finishing my Physics Engine and I'm having troubles figuring what's wrong with a class and why the compiler reports its copy constructor was deleted while using a vector.

---

**Here's my class**

```
const real baumgarteCoef = 0.5f;
// based on GoblinPhysics'
// https://github.com/chandlerprall/GoblinPhysics/blob/master/src/classes/Constraints/ContactConstraint.js
class ContactConstraint : public Constraint {
public:
    ContactConstraint(PhysicalObject* objA, PhysicalObject* objB, const Vector3& position,
                       const Vector3& normal, real penetration)
        : Constraint(objA, objB, (u32)1) {
        collisionPosition = position;
        collisionNormal = normal;
        this->penetration = penetration;
        real r1 = objA->getRestitution();
        real r2 = objB->getRestitution();
        restitutionCoef = Math::SquareRoot(r1 * r2);
        rows[0].lowerLimit = 0.f;
        rows[0].upperLimit = Math::PositiveInfinity;
        collisionPosA = objA->getInverseRotation().rotate(position - objA->getPosition() +
                                                          normal * penetration);
        collisionPosB = objB->getInverseRotation().rotate(position - objB->getPosition() -
                                                          normal * penetration);
    }

    ContactConstraint(const ContactConstraint& c) = default;

    void update(real timeElapsed) {
        auto& row = rows[0];

        if (objA->isStatic()) {
            row.jacobian[0] = 0.f;
            row.jacobian[1] = 0.f;
            row.jacobian[2] = 0.f;
            row.jacobian[3] = 0.f;
            row.jacobian[4] = 0.f;
            row.jacobian[5] = 0.f;
        } else {
            row.jacobian[0] = -collisionNormal.x();
            row.jacobian[1] = -collisionNormal.y();
            row.jacobian[2] = -collisionNormal.z();

            Vector3 v = collisionPosition - objA->getPosition();
            Vector3 v2 = v.cross(collisionNormal);
            row.jacobian[3] = -v2.x();
            row.jacobian[4] = -v2.y();
            row.jacobian[5] = -v2.z();
        }

        if (objB->isStatic()) {
            row.jacobian[6] = 0.f;
            row.jacobian[7] = 0.f;
            row.jacobian[8] = 0.f;
            row.jacobian[9] = 0.f;
            row.jacobian[10] = 0.f;
            row.jacobian[11] = 0.f;
        } else {
            row.jacobian[6] = collisionNormal.x();
            row.jacobian[7] = collisionNormal.y();
            row.jacobian[8] = collisionNormal.z();

            Vector3 v = collisionPosition - objB->getPosition();
            Vector3 v2 = v.cross(collisionNormal);
            row.jacobian[9] = v2.x();
            row.jacobian[10] = v2.y();
            row.jacobian[11] = v2.z();
        }

        // Apply penetration error.
        row.bias = baumgarteCoef * penetration / timeElapsed;
        // Apply restitution
        Vector3 velocity = objA->getLinearVelocity() +
                        collisionPosA.cross(objA->getAngularVelocity()) -
                        objB->getLinearVelocity() - collisionPosB.cross(objB->getAngularVelocity());
        real restitution = (collisionNormal.dot(velocity)) * restitutionCoef;
        row.bias += restitution;
    }

private:
    Vector3 collisionPosition;
    Vector3 collisionNormal;
    Vector3 collisionPosA;
    Vector3 collisionPosB;
    real penetration;
    real restitutionCoef;
};
```

---

**And its parent class**

```
// based on GoblinPhysics'
// https://github.com/chandlerprall/GoblinPhysics/blob/master/src/classes/Constraints/ConstraintRow.js
class Constraint {
public:
    class Row {
    public:
        Constraint* parent;
        real jacobian[12];
        real derivedMass[12];
        real effectiveMass;
        real lowerLimit;
        real upperLimit;
        real bias;
        real multiplier;
        real multiplierCache;
        real eta;

        void computeDerivedMass();
        void computeEffectiveMass();
        void computeEta(real timeDelta);
    };

    Constraint(PhysicalObject* objectA, PhysicalObject* objectB, u32 numRows) {
        objA = objectA;
        objB = objectB;
        rows = std::make_unique<Row[]>(numRows);
        this->numRows = numRows;
        for (u32 i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
            rows[i].parent = this;
        breakingThreshold = 0.f;
        active = true;
    }

    Constraint(const Constraint& c) = default;
    PhysicalObject* objA;
    PhysicalObject* objB;
    std::unique_ptr<Row[]> rows;
    Vector3 lastImpulse;
    u32 numRows;
    real breakingThreshold;
    bool active;

    virtual void update(real timeElapsed) = 0;
};
```

---

**The error** (god have mercy as the compiler could have condensed it)

```
[  9%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/kepler3d.dir/PhysicsEngine/PhysicsEngine.cpp.obj
In file included from D:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/7.3.0/memory:64:0,
                 from D:/msys64/home/ferna/Kepler3D/src/Architecture/Command.h: ,
                 from D:/msys64/home/ferna/Kepler3D/src/Architecture/Architecture.h:3,
                 from D:/msys64/home/ferna/Kepler3D/src/PhysicsEngine/PhysicsEngine.cpp:2:
D:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/7.3.0/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of 'void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = Kepler3D::ContactConstraint; _Args = {Kepler3D::ContactConstraint}]':
D:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/7.3.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:83:18:   required from 'static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<Kepler3D::ContactConstraint*>; _ForwardIterator = Kepler3D::ContactConstraint*; bool _TrivialValueTypes = false]'
D:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/7.3.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:134:15:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<Kepler3D::ContactConstraint*>; _ForwardIterator = Kepler3D::ContactConstraint*]'
D:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/7.3.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:289:37:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<Kepler3D::ContactConstraint*>; _ForwardIterator = Kepler3D::ContactConstraint*; _Tp = Kepler3D::ContactConstraint]'
D:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/7.3.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:311:2:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, _Allocator&) [with _InputIterator = Kepler3D::ContactConstraint*; _ForwardIterator = Kepler3D::ContactConstraint*; _Allocator = std::allocator<Kepler3D::ContactConstraint>]'
D:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/7.3.0/bits/vector.tcc:426:6:   required from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_realloc_insert(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {Kepler3D::PhysicalObject*&, Kepler3D::PhysicalObject*&, const Kepler3D::Vector3&, const Kepler3D::Vector3&, float&}; _Tp = Kepler3D::ContactConstraint; _Alloc = std::allocator<Kepler3D::ContactConstraint>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Kepler3D::ContactConstraint*, std::vector<Kepler3D::ContactConstraint> >; typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer = Kepler3D::ContactConstraint*]'
D:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/7.3.0/bits/vector.tcc:105:21:   required from 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reference std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::emplace_back(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {Kepler3D::PhysicalObject*&, Kepler3D::PhysicalObject*&, const Kepler3D::Vector3&, const Kepler3D::Vector3&, float&}; _Tp = Kepler3D::ContactConstraint; _Alloc = std::allocator<Kepler3D::ContactConstraint>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reference = Kepler3D::ContactConstraint&]'
D:/msys64/home/ferna/Kepler3D/src/PhysicsEngine/Dynamics/ConstraintsManager.h:23:82:   required from here
D:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/7.3.0/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: use of deleted function 'Kepler3D::ContactConstraint::ContactConstraint(const Kepler3D::ContactConstraint&)'
     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
```

---

I'm not sure if the unique pointer on the parent class is making it impossible for the copy-constructor to be derived. I also like to add that in no case I copy the class directly (only emplace), however, copying is default for a vector class due to its inner mechanisms.

---

This line is causing the error in the `ConstraintsManager`

```
contactConstraints.emplace_back(objA, objB, position, normal, penetration);
```

Comment: I'm still staring at this, but I have a feeling that it has to do with inheritance of default constructors. I'd try ditching the `default` copy constructor on `ContactConstraint`, and explicitly declare one that calls the inherited copy constructor. (Just for testing. This is one case where a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  would really come in handy.)

Answer (score 4):

An object that contains an `unique_ptr` cannot be copied as that member (i.e. `rows`) is not copiable by default. You have to provide your own implementation if you need copy.

As far as I know and by looking the error trace, I think that you should be able to move objects instead. Have you tried to provide default move constructor?

```
Constraint(Constraint&& c) = default;
```

I think it would also need to be `noexcept`.

I am not sure if your derived class can be copied and/or moved as I don't have the definition of `Vector3`.

Obviously from the error trace, you need to be able to copy (or move) items because the vector might need to be resize when adding items when it is full.

Although, I believe that in this example you need deep copy, in some cases, you might be able to store `shared_ptr` instead of `unique_ptr` and then you would have a shallow copy constructor automatically generated.

If fact, it would probably works here too but you would then need to be careful no to do accidental copy and then modify an object no realizing that the data is partly shared between those.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. It turns out that the copy constructor could not be derived due to the parent class having a unique_ptr, a simple solution was instead of generating a unique_ptr to my array, i use an std::vector for that purpose.

For future reference, unique_ptrs does not have copy constructyors and must be handled by case.

Comment: While that works, if your `contactConstraints` variable often changes and can become large, if might have a negative impact of performance as a lot of dat get copied. That can be minimized if you `reserve` room before adding items to the `vector`.

Comment: oh that's the least to worry about. Right now I'm focusing and getting things working correctly, optimizations always go at the end.

Comment: If you are worried about the data being copied and would like to contain a shared reference to a pointer, `std::shared_ptr` may work. If you would like to shallow copy the data, `std::vector` works too.